# В чем ошибка алгоритма?

Tags: c

Алгоритм должен возвращать двумерный массив с разделенной по пробелу строкой (тот же split(" ") из Python).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// Добавление char в конец массива char
void append(char* needed, char to_append) {
    int length = strlen(needed);
    needed[length] = to_append;
    needed[length+1] = '\0';
}


char** split(char* input) {
    int space_count = 0;

    // Считаем пробелы
    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == ' ') {
            space_count++;
        }
    }

    // Указатель на указатель на char.
    char **splitted_input;
    // Выделяем память под массивы char
    splitted_input = (char**) malloc((space_count+1) * sizeof(*splitted_input));

    // Хранилище для текущей строки (перед пробелом)
    char word[100] = "";
    int current = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(input); i++) {
        if (input[i] == ' ') {
            printf("NEW: [%d] = %s\n", current, word);
            splitted_input[current] = word;
            current++;
            // Обнуляем весь массив
            memset(word, 0, sizeof(word));
            continue;
        }

        // Если не пробел, то добавляем в конец word новый символ
        append(word, input[i]);
    }


    printf("NEW: [%d] = %s\n\n", current, word);
    // Добавляем текущую строку
    splitted_input[current] = word;

    for (int i = 0; i < space_count+1; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", splitted_input[i]);
    }


    // Еще не имею понятия, как здесь лучше освободить память splitted_input
    return splitted_input;
}



int main() {
    char input[20] = "hi everyone";

    char** need = split(input);

    return 0;
}
```

Выводит:

```
NEW: [0] = hi
NEW: [1] = everyone

everyone
everyone
```

Не понимаю, почему splitted_input[0] тоже равняется everyone

Comment: Алгоритм концептуально некорректный, так как между словами могут присутствовать несколько пробелов (не говоря уж о знаках табуляции), а не всего лишь один пробел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Непосредственный ответ на вопрос: они оба указывают на один и тот же `word`.

Другая проблема: из функции возвращается массив с указателями на локальную переменную.

Решение. Для `splitted_input[current]` выделяйте память на новую строку, куда копируйте содержимое `word`:

```
splitted_input[current] = strdup(word);
```

Comment: да, теперь понял, спасибо
char w1[100];
strcpy(w1, word);
splitted_input[current] = w1;

Правильный способ? Каким еще способом еще можно это реализовать (ради интереса)?

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный Нет, это неправильно. `w1` - это тоже локальная переменная. Память выделенная на этот массив будет считаться свободной, как только выполнение выйдет из области ее видимости.

Comment: это было предположительное решение проблемы с выделением памяти на новую строку, а не с локальной переменной. А насчет как раз второй проблемы: у меня ведь splitted_input - динамическая переменная (т.к. выделяю память с помощью malloc), а значит память будет доступна и после завершения функции, нет?

Comment: @ГошаОбыночный В Вашем коде Вы динамически выделяете память на одномерный массив из `char*`. На сами массивы `char`-ов память тоже должна выделяться динамически.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

```
splitted_input[current] = word;
```

На каждой итерации цикла указатель `splitted_input[current]` ставится на один и тот же массив `word`. Разумеется будет выводиться одна и та же строка, если все указатели указывают в одно и то же место.